# RecyclerView scroll get frezz/scroll slowly in NestedScrollView

Tags: android, list, android-recyclerview, pagination, android-nestedscrollview

I have NestedScrollView. In NestedScrollView contains two RecyclerView that both scroll vertically.

when first RecyclerView list scrolling end/stop then second RecyclerView list stared scrolling.

While at first time when scrolling is started screen getting freeze/ scroll slowly . After sometime smoothly scrolling happen.

*Why first Time of Scrolling screen getting freeze? How to avoid screen freeze/scroll slowly?*

***Because of NestedScrollView, Without scrolling continuously onScrollMethod and EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(Used for pagination)get called.How to avoid getting call of EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener method.***

I am adding my layout code. waiting for answer.

```
                <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout              
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="First List" />

                                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                                    android:id="@+id/rvFirstList"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="vertical"
                                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_4" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="Secound List" />

                                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                                    android:id="@+id/secoundRecyclerView"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="vertical"
                                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_4" />

                            </LinearLayout> 

                        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

                    
                </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your view hierarchy doesn't seem right.
Your start tags are:

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
  <LinearLayout
```

And your closing tags aren't matching

```
  </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Swap NestedScrollView with LinearLayout at the end.

Then try adding this:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

To your <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
block

Comment: I tried adding app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
 in <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
block , does not fix this issue.

Comment: actually you are doing wrong. By using one recyclerview you can achieve this. Just need to do some extra work in your adapter

Comment: I want pagination on both RecyclerView separately,

Answer (score 0):

try

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)
```

on both of your recyclerViews

Comment: I already written these, but issue not solved